# How to get JWindow to immediately draw

Tags: java, swing

How do I get a JWindow to immediately draw? In my example below there is a FULL 2 seconds between the window displaying and drawing as measured from the log output "done" to "painting jwindow". When the window is first displayed it is empty. Two seconds later, the image "splash-screen.png" is displayed.

I do not want to use the built-in splash screen support in Java. It has problems. Please, let's not get into that. I already spent days researching it... it doesn't work for my case (not fully described here).

I have run this code many times in succession to see if the delay is reduced... it remains at 2 seconds... very consistently. I'm running on macOS 10.14.1 and JDK 10.0.2.

Here is my SSCCE:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class MyApp {
    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyApp.class.getName());
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final JWindow[] startupScreen = {null};
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().setPriority(10);
                LOG.info("edt thread priority: "+Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
                startupScreen[0] = new JWindow() {
                    @Override
                    public void paint(Graphics g) {
                        super.paint(g);
                        LOG.info("painting jwindow");
                    }
                };
                /*
                LOG.info("set layout");
                startupScreen[0].setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                */
                LOG.info("add splash image");
                startupScreen[0].add(
                    new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                        MyApp.class.getResource("splash-screen.png")
                    )), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                LOG.info("pack");
                startupScreen[0].pack();
                LOG.info("set relative location");
                startupScreen[0].setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                LOG.info("set visible");
                startupScreen[0].setVisible(true);
                startupScreen[0].repaint();
                startupScreen[0].revalidate();
                LOG.info("done");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I use JDK8 on Windows 7. I loaded a full screen image and the window and image came up right away with no noticeable delay.

Answer (score 0):

Likely bottleneck:

```
startupScreen[0].add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
        MyApp.class.getResource("splash-screen.png"))), 
        BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

or more specifically, here:

```
MyApp.class.getResource("splash-screen.png")
```

as you're reading in an uncompressed and possibly large .png image resource. Solutions include not requiring the image or reading in a smaller compressed .jpg image.

Comment: The image is seventeen kilobytes. I'm confident that is not the problem.

Comment: I want to explore your suggestion that the line adding the JLabel may be the bottleneck... since it is not the image size, what do you think it could be? I have a desire to test directly drawing the image in the paint method instead of using JLabel and ImageIcon. Do you think that would help?